# Kentico first install Admin site not accessible

Tags: kentico

After installing Kentico 10 on windows Server 2012 standard, 
the administration page is blank (after login).

In the console, I have the following message:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'toArray' of undefined or null
>   reference  GetResource.ashx, line 1 character 1697

It's my first install and I don't know how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install it directly on the server or move the files to the server?  I'd suggest installing locally and moving it to the server.  The issue could be with permissions.  Make sure the user running IIS has read/write permissions to the directory Kentico is in.

Comment: It was a custom installation, If I use the basic installation it's working

Comment: Ok installing by default, then publishing where I want it to be is ok.
Thx

Comment: What do you mean "custom installation"?

Comment: Is the page completely blank? Can you see Kentico logo at the top left corner?